# Can I turn a cow into a mooshroom?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to turn a normal cow into a mooshroom?

[image: MOO!]

Comment: I think I speak for many people here with this: What?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, they spawn in new mushroom biomes. However, the reverse is possible, using shears:

Answer (score 2):

As of right now (now being 1.9 pre-release) No, there isn't.

Answer (score -8):

I also found that my cows had changed.

If you are in a mushroom area, or swamp, and you spawn a cow, it should be normal. If you then leave that cow it will eventually turn into a mooshroom.

It will usually take about 5 hours in real-time.